# PHP Submission form into MySQL db formatting

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have created a blog using PHP that submits a form into a MySQL databse. It works perfectly. What i want to know is how to get it to recognise when i've pressed enter to create a new line or to record a ' without getting a MySQL error. Basically i want to turn a normal submission form into a submission form like is used on this website.

```
<tr>
 <td>Blog Title:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="edt" name="BlogTitle"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Blog Content:</td>
 <td><textarea name="BlogCont" cols="50" rows="10" id="edt"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?=$_SESSION['Name']?>"></td>
 <td><input type="submit" id="but" value="Post"></td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br). As for the other thing, are you escaping your inputs properly before inserting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new lines with enter use `nl2br` ([manual](http://php.net/nl2br)), for apostrophe you have to escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string` ([manual](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)).